# Horizontal spacing in ChartJS Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js plugin.
I want to reduce the horizontal spacing.

Image 1 : I try

[image]

Image 2 : I want

[image]

[JSFiddle Link Here!](https://jsfiddle.net/9br26mcz/)

HTML Code Here

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
```

CSS Code Here

```
canvas {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

JS Code Here

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ['April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'facebook',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
        data: [179, 201]
    }, {
        label: 'instagram',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        backgroundColor: '#e8361c',
        data: [31, 47]
    }]
},

    options: {
      responsive: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 0
            },
            gridLines: {
              display:false
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          display:true,
          barPercentage: 0.7,
          categoryPercentage: 0.3,
          gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    position:'bottom'
  },
    animation:false
  }
});
```

I want to reduce the interval between categories. I do not know if there is a corresponding option. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to generate the charts?

Comment: @Justin Code Here! https://jsfiddle.net/9br26mcz/